# Displaying single image field in django template not working?

Tags: django, django-templates

Here I returned the only one model field value using the `values()` method but I got problem while displaying this field value in template. How can I do it ?

views.py

```
def homepage(request):
   image = MyModel.objects.filter(active=True).values('login_bg_image').last()
   print(image) #this is working fine 
   return render{request,'homepage.html',{'image':image}
```

homepage.html

```
 <img src="{{image.login_bg_image.url}}" width="200" height="200">
```

When I do only `{{image.login_bg_image}}` then it displays the image name but after adding `.url` it does not displays picture

Comment: you don't need `values()`

Comment: because i wanted to return only one field so

Comment: one field you use `get()` not `filter()`

Comment: `get()` will return the single object not the object's single field

Comment: return the whole object, then access the field you want in the template

Comment: @Moha369 this was not my question.

Comment: then use `getattr()` to get a single field

Comment: The code works perfectly in the view .The only problem is while displaying in the template.

Comment: tried to delete `.url` ?

Comment: can you post your view? view should return a HttpResponse.  Here you are returning a dict.

Comment: @NalinDobha l have returned a correct template with that dictionary.

Comment: can you post the code that you are using in your view?

Comment: this is the code which i am using in my view

Comment: No, show the whole view and the template.

Comment: @DanielRoseman added my view

Comment: @DanielRoseman when i do only `{{image.login_bg_image}}` then it displays the image name but after adding `.url` it doesnot displays picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `values()`. That gives you a string for `login_bg_image`, rather than a FieldFile object with a `url` property.

Generally it's a bad idea to use `values` unless you know you need it anyway. Just pass actual model instances.

```
image = MyModel.objects.filter(active=True).last()
```